# scanning qr code using webcam, fetching the image from the wencam

Tags: javascript, php, qr-code

I have this code that scans and decode qr image with the help of this source code https://github.com/khanamiryan/php-qrcode-detector-decoder, it scans the image file from your documents..but I want to scan the qr using my webcam.

the qr code scanner script is this

```
  <?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != "POST"){
    header("location:take-attendance.php");
    die();
}

require "vendor/autoload.php";

$qrcode = new Zxing\QrReader($_FILES['qrimage']['tmp_name']);
$text = $qrcode->text();

var_dump($text);

?>
```

then my webcam that take snapshot goes like this

```
 <form action="decode.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<script src="webcam.js"></script> <!--source code script from github for webcam config-->

    <div id="my_camera" style="width:320px; height:240px;"></div>
    <div id="my_result"></div>

    <script type=text/javascript>
        Webcam.attach( '#my_camera' );

        function take_snapshot() {
            Webcam.snap( function(data_uri) {
                document.getElementById('my_result').innerHTML = '<img src="'+data_uri+'"/>';
            } );
        }
    </script>

    <a href="javascript:void(take_snapshot())">Take Snapshot</a>
```

so I click the take snapshot the image will appear as an img src and I want that image to be fetch if I click scan so that means I need to replace this code

```
$qrcode = new Zxing\QrReader($_FILES['qrimage']['tmp_name']);
```

with the file name that is been generated when I click that snapshot which is this

```
<img src="'+data_uri+'"/>
```

but the thing is I don't know the format on how to write the code, this is my idea but it doesn't work though

```
$qrcode = new Zxing\QrReader($_FILES['data_uri']);
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You don't send anything in your form.

Snapshot generated in base64 format, so you can only send it as string to server and decode to image.

But much simpler is use JS QR Decoder like this https://github.com/colcodev/qrcode-decoder-js

```
qrcode.decode(data_uri)
```

And then if you need send result to server via simple input

```
Webcam.attach( '#my_camera' );

function take_snapshot() {
    Webcam.snap(function(data_uri) {
        document.getElementById('my_result').innerHTML = '<img src="'+data_uri+'"/> - '+qrcode.decode(data_uri);
    });
}
```

Comment: so does qrcode.decode(date_uri) works on my current qrcode scanner source code sir?

Comment: @dread install this library and add to your page and it will work. And then you will not need Zxing\QrReader

Comment: how should I write my code sir after scanning, I'd like to print the information of the qrcode, I am sorry I am new to java script sir

Comment: @dread added example code should output qr code text alongside of image

Comment: How should I add this to my code sir can you show me how it's done, cause I have this error qrcode is not defined
    at qrcode-decoder.min.js:3 and I basically wrote it like this <script src="qrcode-decoder-js-master/lib/qrcode-decoder.min.js">
  qrcode.decode(data_uri);
  </script>

Comment: @dread download lib here https://github.com/colcodev/qrcode-decoder-js/blob/master/lib/qrcode-decoder.min.js

Then put to your site folder and add this.

```<script src="path/to/qrcode-decoder.min.js"></script>```

```qrcode.decode(data_uri)``` put to ```Webcam.snap(function(data_uri)``` - example above in answer. Added to end of line ```document.getElementById('my_result'```

Comment: I tried that sir but I got the following error qrcode is not defined
    at take-attendance.php:134
    at func (webcam.js:877)
    at Object.snap (webcam.js:890)
    at take_snapshot (take-attendance.php:132)
    at <anonymous>:1:6

Comment: then I have this error too sir Uncaught ReferenceError: qrcode is not defined
    at qrcode-decoder.min.js:3
(anonymous) @ qrcode-decoder.min.js:3